# Как в словаре в качестве ключа вписать число?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def min_max_dictionary(**kwargs_):

    min_key , max_key = min(kwargs_.values()) , max(kwargs_.values())

    return [min_key, max_key]

print(min_max_dictionary(h = 1, e = 2, ll = 3, o = 4))
```

Здесь вместо букв должны быть числа.

Answer (score 1):

```
def min_max_key_dict(d):
        return[min(d),max(d)]
print(min_max_dict({1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4}))
```

---

```
[1, 4]
```